# Change layout based on device or host

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm rewriting our old website to Node.js with Sails.js. We have 2 type of layouts, for desktops and for mobile devices. Previously we were changing them according to the host. When someone was entering our website from mobile device he was redirected to m.website.com and there was mobile layout. It was one application on one server.

Is there a way in Sails.js to do something like this? Or should i just build my own class with methods

```
getLayout(layout,isMobile)
getView(view,isMobile)
```

which will return proper view & layout for each controller? Is there a better way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional on the client side. Desktop browsers don't support the orientation property so this should work;

`if(typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined'){...}`

Then request/set the stylesheet based on this.

Comment: I want completely different layout for mobile. Not only different CSS file.